# View does not update the current date (Django)

Tags: django, date, datetime

It is implemented to call get_week in view.
'now', which is printed directly as a template, is normally displayed, but the result of get_week, which is output through the module, is output as the value before 1 week.
If you have fixed a similar bug, please help
For reference, the source code below is a function to generate a weekly report.

```
#: 금주 보고서는 read/modify
@login_required
def weekly_report_view(request):
    context = {
        'site_title': '취약점 Dashboard',
        'site_header': '취약점 Dashboard',
        'user': request.user,
        'has_permission': True,
        'now': datetime.datetime.now()
    }

    this_week = False
    week_num = request.GET.get('week_num')
    if week_num is None:
        start_date, end_date, week_num = get_week()
    stats = Statistics2020.objects.filter(week_num=week_num)
    if len(stats) == 0:
        return redirect('/dashboard/stat/weekly/create')
    stat = stats[0]
    if stat.end_date >= datetime.date.today():
        this_week = True
        stat_date_update(stat.week_num, stat.start_date, stat.end_date)
    else:
        pass
    context['stat'] = Statistics2020.objects.get(week_num=week_num)
    context['raw'] = json.loads(stat.raw)
    context['this_week'] = this_week
    return render(request, template_name='dashboard/weekly_report.html', context=context)


def get_week(today=datetime.datetime.now().date()):
    shift = BASE_WEEK_START - 1
    print(today)
    week_number = today.isoweekday() - shift
    if week_number <= 0:
        week_number += 7
    startdate = today - datetime.timedelta(days=week_number-1)
    enddate = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=6)
    #print('%s~%s'% (startdate, enddate))
    return startdate, enddate, int(startdate.isocalendar()[1])
```

Comment: `before 1 week` = date the server started

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> def hello(now=datetime.datetime.now()):
    print(now)

>>> hello()
2020-07-30 13:25:34.731001
>>> hello()
2020-07-30 13:25:34.731001
>>> hello()
2020-07-30 13:25:34.731001
>>> hello(datetime.datetime.now())
2020-07-30 13:25:53.446748
>>> hello(datetime.datetime.now())
2020-07-30 13:25:59.613445
>>>
```